# LCM of Monomial doesn't produce a LCM?

Tags: functions

I was trying to teach my 7th grader how to calculate the LCM of two monomials and plugged in some numbers to show her how it worked.  I was surprised to find that the resulting expression does not actually produce the LCM but only a common multiple.  For example LCM(ab,bc) = abc but LCM(2*3, 3*4) = 12 (not 2*3*4).  So why is it called the LCM of a Monomial instead of just CM?

Comment: The difference is that in the former, you treat $a$ and $b$ as **indeterminates**, things that do not take values, but are just objects in their own right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

${\rm lcm}(ab,bc) = b\,{\rm lcm}(a,c) = abc/\gcd(a,c)\,\ (= abc\iff \gcd(a,c) = 1)\ $ but you have $\,\gcd(a,c)=2$

If by monomial you mean elements of the *polynomial* ring $\,\Bbb Z[a,b,c]\,$ then you cannot expect lcms and gcds to be preserved under evaluation, e.g. $\,(a,b) = 1\,$ but evaluated at $\,a,b = n,n$ the gcd $= n$.

Answer (score 1):

In a Monomial we don't know if $c$ is a multiple of $a$ (or/and $b$) or not. So it doesn't give the least CM.